# Where do I find the LibTypes and LibGIS units for FreePascal?

Tags: libraries, freepascal

I found some Pascal code in the supplementary material of a paper. After the metadata comment, the program starts with

```
unit LibLPMMain;

interface

uses
  {$IfDef DLLShapes}LibFastShareMem,{$EndIf}
  SysUtils, Classes, Math, Linux, SyncObjs,
  {$IfNDef CONSOLE}
  ExtCtrls,
  {$EndIf}
  LibTypes, LibGIS, LibFiles, LibStats, LibPhyStats,
  LibGeometry, LibMCMC,
  LibMatrix, LibProbDistrib;
```

I have loaded the file into Lazarus and attempted compile it using FreePascal, which complains

```
LibLPMMain.pas(37,3) Fatal: Cannot find LibTypes used by LibLPMMain of the Project Inspector.
```

Are the units listed here libraries I should be able to find somewhere – and if so, where – or do I have to contact the authors of the paper to provide me with those libraries before I can attempt to execute their simulation?

Comment: Yes, these are not standard units, so you need to query the origin of the source or take your chances with google

Answer (score 1):

i found this by searching Github:
https://github.com/EcoComp-UFG/EcoSimulation/blob/8b3adaf99f65db0a94e4fa2c8bf0663d0a0506f1/code_in_delphi/paleo_data/LibTypes.pas 
https://github.com/terrobyte-github/CRM/blob/320010aa54137463ee17646b66c54de0626a13ca/Common/smxLibTypes.pas 
http://freshmeat.sourceforge.net/projects/libgis 
http://gvsigce.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Compiling_GRASS_GIS 
https://github.com/GRASS-GIS/grass-ci 
https://github.com/Anaphory/settlement-of-americas/blob/cf81e35b569afbeef986a172509d27db00b792f9/supplement/gavin2017processbased/LibLPMMain.pas 
Seems like it is port of some graphic/server libraries. Have no further information, sorry, but, try porting this. 
Further information shows, that it is either can be a Lazarus integration of QGRISS or delphi of GRASS_GIS,
The're just not as shared as must be, or just paidware